# window.onbeforeunload() is not working on Firefox browser close

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

window.onbeforeunload() is working on browser close of IE and Chrome, but it is not working in case of Firefox(Works only on tab close) browser close.

My Requirement:: I am capturing mobile number, email id, Firstname and lastName etc.. using document.getelementById() and calling a service upon closing browser or tab.

Problem : Service is getting called in case of IE and GC(tab/browser close) but not in case of FireFox.

Any help is substantially appreciated......

Comment: Tried this function and it worked for me. Can you try to console.log anything and put it on the function it self ? to see if it is triggeredat least. window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
  e.returnValue = dialogText;
  return dialogText;
};

Comment: The above code by @chaibialaa worked once you interact with the page once. If I just open the page, but don't do nothing on the page then it won't prompt. This is the way Firefox works which can be read on there docs: [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Comment: Code given by @Chaibi Alaa asking prompt to leave the page or not, but it should not ask for any prompt as per my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if you are returning a string or not.

> The function should assign a string value to the returnValue property of the Event object and return the same string.

2.
It is advised to use `onunload` instead of `onbeforeunload` as the latter is often reported to work inconsistently and Mozilla's [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) also indicate variation in implementation of the standard the event by browsers. Although,IMO unload events are not really reliable and one should ignore them when can.

Comment: Why he should use onUnload instead ? The onBeforeUnload is a correct builtin function !

Comment: PS : I could've commented instead of answering but I don't have enough reputation for it.

Comment: onunload()  is not working on browser close of firefox, and @Uberish I don't want to return anything back to ajax call, just I need to get the values entered in the fields of Mobile Number and Email etc.... and I just wanted to call the service that's it.......

Comment: please refer syntax and notes section on this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Comment: still if you don't want it to return any value and generate any popup, have a  try at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10031915/5714267)