# window.onunload() is not working in Firefox ? works in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Can anyone tell me how to fire the `window.onunload` event in Firefox?

My JavaScript is:

```
window.onunload = function () {
        logout();
};
```

I need to logout the chat session when my application get closes.

Any alternative to jQuery is there?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: What does `logout()` do? Does it fire a AJAX request? If so, you'll have to make it synchronous. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Yes I am using the Ajax for logout() .It does not enter in to the **window.onunload**.

Comment: @frenchie Already used and not worked in Firefox.

Comment: How do you know it does not enter it? Are there any errors?

Comment: No but I cheked with alert.

Comment: Putting alerts into the `unload` event is unreliable. Most likely your code is executing you just don't see it. Make sure your AJAX request is synchronous and tell us if it works then.

Comment: @Jan Hančič I changed my ajax request to synchronous and its worked. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window.onbeforeunload and window.onunload is not working in Firefox , Safari , Opera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645011/window-onbeforeunload-and-window-onunload-is-not-working-in-firefox-safari-o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for Jan Hančič.

I got the solution for onunload in firefox by changing the **asynchronous** in to **synchronous** call request.

And its worked well...