# $(window).unload(function(){}); is not fired in Firefox and opera?

Tags: javascript, firefox, opera, jquery

My previous post is [window.onbeforeunload and window.onunload is not working in Firefox, Safari, Opera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645011/window-onbeforeunload-and-window-onunload-is-not-working-in-firefox-safari-o) and it not worked in this situation. So I created a new thread.

Now this works in `IE`, `safari`, and `chrome`.

only `beforeunload` event fired in `firefox` and `unload` not fired.

Both not working in `Opera`.

My jQuery will be:

```js
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
  return 'Are you sure want to LOGOUT the session ?';
});

$(window).unload(function () {
  closeWindow();
});

function closeWindow() {
  alert('fdf');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'Test.jsp',
    async: false,
    //data : "userId="+encodeURIComponent(userId)+"&secureKey="+encodeURIComponent(secureKey)+"&nickname="+encodeURIComponent(name)+"&sid="+Math.random() ,
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
    scriptCharset: 'utf-8',
    dataType: 'html',
    //alert(sessionId+" "+userId+ " "+secureKey+" "+message);

    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      //alert("status :"+xhr.status+"\nthrownError : "+thrownError+"\nresponseText : "+xhr.responseText);
    },

    success: function (responseData, status) {
      //alert("LogoutAction Response Data : "+ responseData +"\nStatus : "+status);
      var checkMsg = $.trim(responseData);

      if (checkMsg != 'null' && checkMsg.length != 0 && checkMsg != null) {
        alert('Window close : ' + checkMsg);
      }
    },
  });
}
```

My `Test.jsp` will be ,

```
<%  System.out.println("Window is closed !"); 
out.println("Window is closed !");   %>
```

Comment: ajax calls is asynchronous, so browser will not wait until response is returned, ajax success callback will never fired. Do you get first alert with "fdf"?

Comment: @Tommi I made the `async: false` in my code. Check it.

Comment: Indeed. Didn't mention it.

Comment: I mentioned this in `Jquery-ajax`. Please check it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return something from your unload event callback -

```
$(window).unload(function() {
        closeWindow();
        return "some string";
});
```

Comment: why you asked me to return the string ? and not helped.

Comment: No such thing happened. Any more ideas ?