# IE doesn't execute my code 'onunload'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I need to execute some code before leaving the browser, I implemented this:

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function () { return 'Are you sure?'; };
    window.onunload = function () { releaseLocking(); };
```

It works pretty well with Google Chrome. When closing GC: a message is shown,

- if I click on the button 'stay on the page', nothing will happen. Perfect.
- if I click on the button 'leave the page', the code under releaseLocking will be executed. Perfect.

I have problems with Internet Explorer.

- if I click on the button 'stay on the page', nothing will happen. Perfect.
- if I click on the button 'leave the page', the code under releaseLocking won't get executed.

Any idea?

I searched a lot but didnt found a solution.

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

```
var releaseLocking = function() {
    // Release only if lock is set on the current user
    if (transport().lockedById() == 5) { // 5 is dummy (Jean Dupont for testing)
        transport().lockedById(null);
        transport().lockedTime(null);
        return ctxTransport.saveChanges(SILENTSAVE);
    }
};
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jquery?  If you used jquery your problem might go away.

Comment: I added jquery in tags before I am ok with a solution with jQuery if something is possible...

Comment: What does `releaseLocking` do? How do you know it's not run?

Comment: try it like this `$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){...});`

Comment: I know this releaseLocking is not run because I still have some data in my database which is removed in the releaseLocking. It is ok with GC.

Comment: did you try run releaseLocking() manually from IE?

Comment: @Bronzato: Are you sure? Maybe just the `if()` condition is failing. Have you tried a little basic debugging, like putting a `console.log(...)` first thing inside the handler?

Comment: @Bronzato most likely `releaseLocking` is run, but the AJAX it fires isn't sent.

Comment: Ofar: yes I tried to set releaseLocking in the onbeforeunload. It works but that's not ok for me because user can refuse to qui the page... so I cannot run this code in this case.

Comment: @Bronzato check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14746862/568414

Comment: @Ofar: I have no way of changing from asynchronous to synchronous (no control on that).

Comment: BTW...What IE version are you using?

Comment: @Crazy yes I'm sure: even an alert in the `window.onunload` is not executed in IE.

Comment: @Ofear: IE10 Under Win8

Answer (score 0):

It's seems IE have bug where the unload event wouldn't fire on a specific page on a site.

the unload event never fired since all the contents of the page hadn't finished loading before it's navigated to another page.

**try stopping it before you unload**

try this:

```
function fixUnload() {
    // Is there things still loading, then fake the unload event
    if (document.readyState == 'interactive') {
        function stop() {
            // Prevent memory leak
            document.detachEvent('onstop', stop);

            // Call unload handler
            unload();
        };

        // Fire unload when the currently loading page is stopped
        document.attachEvent('onstop', stop);

        // Remove onstop listener after a while to prevent the unload function
        // to execute if the user presses cancel in an onbeforeunload
        // confirm dialog and then presses the stop button in the browser
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            document.detachEvent('onstop', stop);
        }, 0);
    }
};

function unload() {
    alert('Unload event occured.');
};

window.attachEvent('onunload', unload);
window.attachEvent('onbeforeunload', fixUnload);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure all the content of my page finished loading because I waited enough time (furthermore I work locally).

Comment: I think it's worth a shut.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work: when I close the browser, it closed without any message.

Answer (score 0):

These types of events are very unreliable.. what if the user's browser crashes (lol ie!) I was able to achieve the same outcome by using a heartbeat and polling the server every 20-30 seconds (or longer idk what your duration may be) and using that to handle the exiting event.. I had a locking mechanism in this app too.

Good luck.

Comment: Do you mean you querry the server every 20-30 seconds to say 'hello, I'm still there, don't release the lock' ?

Comment: Exactly, you can extend it maybe to check for mouse or keyboard events to do a real idle timeout if you wish. Take a look at facebook's xhrs.