# Why is jQuery onbeforeunload not working in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: jquery, onbeforeunload

jQuery `onbeforeunload` is not working in Chrome and Firefox. It works properly in IE and Safari.

```
jQuery(window).bind('onbeforeunload' ,function () {
    mymethod();
});
```

Above code works properly in IE and in Safari but not in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: What is inside `mymethod();` and how it works in other browsers ?

Comment: I tried simple alert. Even this doesn't work. By the way it does an ajax call.

Comment: using alert in this case might be the worst choice, as browsers try hard to eliminate possibility for the developer to force user to stay at the site, and alert, being a modal function, could be used for that :)

Answer (score 41):

According to MDN's [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload) reference,

> The function should assign a string value to the returnValue property of the Event object and return the same string.

Observe [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XZAWS/)

```
jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {
    var message = "Why are you leaving?";
    e.returnValue = message;
    return message;
});
```

Note that **certain events may be ignored**:

> [...] the HTML5 specification states that calls to window.showModalDialog(), **window.alert()**, window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods **may be ignored** during this event.

An important note about AJAX:

If you're trying to make an AJAX call when the user is leaving the request may be cancelled (interrupted) before it finishes. You can turn off the `async` option as a way around this. For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/",
    type: "GET",
    async: false
});
```

***Update 2017:***

Many browsers no longer support custom text in the alert dialog when the user is leaving.

The latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari do not display any custom text.

Edge and IE still support this.

***Update 2021:***

Only Internet Explorer supports a custom text message.

Comment: Just adding a return value fixed this for me.

Comment: Hi Rowan , I noticed if we return something it does show confirmation popup what if we want to remove that confirm popup also