# why unload and beforeunload not working on firefox? is there any solution?

Tags: ajax, onbeforeunload

**On Chrome its working properly but on firefox its not working**

```
function myfoo(){
         // Write your logic here
           $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update.php",
            dataType: 'json',
             data: {Eventid: 'Eventid',Seats:'Seats'},
            success: function (r) {}

});
    }
```

**When unloading window**

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
   return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

**when unloading call function**

```
$(window).on('unload', function () {
   console.log('calling ajax');
   myfoo();
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is jQuery onbeforeunload not working in Chrome and Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776544/why-is-jquery-onbeforeunload-not-working-in-chrome-and-firefox)

Comment: it is working. it just isn't doing what you'd hope it does. this behavior is well documented.

Comment: can you help me in this code?

Comment: in chrome this code running perfectly, but in firefox it it does not updating records on window close. like in chrome it is do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "onbeforeunload" and "unload" is working but in your scenario you are expecting to send ajax call. so try changing ajax asynchronous to false.

```
function myfoo(){
         // Write your logic here
           $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
             data: {Eventid: 'Eventid',Seats:'Seats'},
            success: function (r) {}

});
    }
```

Comment: can you please edit my code. it would be helpful for me.

Comment: great brother. you have done great job. thank you very much