# Using beforeunload event handler in MS Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

In IE I used the following AJAX callback in the beforeunload event handler.
Now using MS Edge the AJAX will not fire.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
    stopTimer();
    $.post("/LabelPrintingWebApp/InitialControllerServlet",
    {lifecycle:"filecleanup",
    source:0},'json');
});
```

Comment: Are you certain that your function is being called? I tested a bit and found that if there has been no user interaction on the page then the function is not called in Edge, but is in IE11. The answer from @MarekWysmułek at [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081699/why-onbeforeunload-event-is-not-firing discusses the issues.

Comment: @AHaworth so you were able to get MS Edge to fire an AJAX callback if the page was interacted with?

Comment: I didn’t try that, but I did see that it had entered the function.