# Send a ajax when leave button is clicked onbeforeunload jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, browser

I am using following code on a html page

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {  
    return "You have made changes on this page that you have not yet confirmed. If you navigate away from this page you will lose your
    unsaved changes";    }
```

when a user try to leave the current page the i ask the user a confirmation either he/she want to leave the page or not. there are two button 'leave the page' and 'cancle'

How can i know if user click on the leave button then i have to send a ajax request (that ajax request do some action in DB) .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show some HTML please?

Comment: @AminJafari Why do you need HTML?

Answer (score 0):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls8LL86x/)

```
window.onunload=callajax;

function callajax() {
   /*Your ajax call code*/
   return "ajax response";//returning ajax response
}
```

You can use like this also:

```
window.onbeforeunload = callajax;
function callajax() {
   /*Your ajax call code*/
   return "ajax response";//returning ajax response
}
```

Comment: it is not working..i am using following code

``window.onbeforeunload =callajax;
function callajax() {
  $.post( "test.php", function( data ) {});
   return "ajax response";//returning ajax response
}``

the ajax call also execute when i click on the cancle.. i want to send ajax on leave button call

Answer (score 0):

[window.onbeforeunload and window.onunload is not working in Firefox , Safari , Opera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645011/window-onbeforeunload-and-window-onunload-is-not-working-in-firefox-safari-o)

Please take a look at this link , it is exactly what you are asking for . The trick is to use synchronous ajax in your function for window.onunload :

```
window.onunload=function(){
xmlhttp.open("GET","/YourAction",false);
}
```

The above function will be called when the user presses the "leave the page" button , and since the ajax request would be synchronous , the document would only unload completely when the ajax request finishes.

Comment: it is not working i am using following code
``window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return  "Are you sure want to leave this page ?";
}; 
window.onunload = function () {
    xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php",false);
};``