# Is it possible to track before a browser is closed?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering what methods could be used to detect when a browser window, or tab just before it is closed?

I'm guessing there are a few ways, but I'm not sure of the best.

I've seen spam sites that give a pop up window saying "are you sure you want to exit" before the browser window will close. Anyone know how to achieve this in code? Would javascript be the only/best solution?

Tracking the mouse (when it moves to top right hand corner) might be a good way, again in probably only in javascript?

Perhaps cookies can do this?

Any thoughts or suggestions would be wonderful.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: the follow stackoverflow post should help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645011/window-onbeforeunload-and-window-onunload-is-not-working-in-firefox-safari-o

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)

Answer (score 2):

You can use onbeforeunload event:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload',function(){
   alert('closing');
});
```

Or,

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   alert('closing');
};
```

If you want to prevent default behavior then you can use it like below:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;     //Gecko + IE
  return confirmationMessage;                                //Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
});
```

[see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Comment: that won't help if the user kills the window or the process!

Comment: Nothing will help if the user does that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return "Do you really want to close the page?";
    }
```

Put any of your code within that function to run when a user is about to close the page