# Form Exit Inquiry

Tags: forms

I have a form on a webpage and I can't seem to get the completion rate up.  I thought about having a pop up or some kind of message asking people if they came to the page in error why did they or if they are leaving without filling out the form why is that.  Any thoughts or way of doing this so that the question would show on exit but not on form submission?

Comment: No, build analytics tools, and find out where most people are abandoning your form (naive example: send a ping to your server whenever someone fills an input, then compile the information to see where people stop filling them). If a user abandoned your form, it's likely that they're already frustrated, and would not want to answer your survey.

Comment: There is the `unbeforeunload` event that allows for a last-ditch effort to stop a user, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645011/window-onbeforeunload-and-window-onunload-is-not-working-in-firefox-safari-o but as Madara Uchicha says, this is a really intrusive option typically used by spammy popups that you didn't want to open in the first place. "Soft" options like analyzing what goes wrong, and offering instant help (live chat?) are *vastly* preferable.

Comment: Will this work just on form submission?

Comment: No, whenever the users leaves the current document (including submitting the form, for which you will have to build a specific provision so the alert doesn't fire in that case)