# Javascript code inside beforeunload callback not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have added code to change web page color on `beforeunload` event:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (){
    $('.navbar-collapse').css({background: 'blue'});
    console.log("Hello unload");
    return null;
  }
```

- This code works properly on Chrome and Firefox but it doesn't work on Safari browser.
- However, when I debug this code in Safari, when stepping over each line of code in the callback function, id DOES changes background color.
- When I navigate by clicking on an url on page and then click back button on browser, the background color is changed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

[`window.onbeforenload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) is "magic" in the sense that it is special and more and more browsers are restricting what it can do.

Some browsers will let you display a custom message, other browers are free to ignore this event entirely.

In short: Don't try to do anything but return a null or non-null value and hope for the best.  It is out of your hands.

You might want to see this answer too:  [window.onbeforeunload and window.onunload is not working in Firefox , Safari , Opera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645011/window-onbeforeunload-and-window-onunload-is-not-working-in-firefox-safari-o)