# removing eventlistener for beforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to implement a popup (bootstrap modal style) that would be triggered as web visitor leaves my site.

I tried different alternatives of:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
$("#sModal").modal('show');
return 'Take our survey before you leave.';
});
```

However, it didn't work in FF while worked fine in IE. I had another problem also, that the "Do you want to leave or stay" alert was being displayed on any link click on my website itself, across all browser types, as the whole page was being loaded.

I got around this by looping through all my anchor tags and adding a click listener to remove the beforeunload listener using:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
        allLinks[i].addEventListener("click", removeBeforeUnload, false);
    }
};
```

The removeBeforeUnload function just used the

```
$(window).unbind('beforeunload');
```

Getting back to actually make the popoup/modal appear on all browsers, i used the code from this stackoverflow answer after my document completes loading:

[window.onbeforeunload and window.onunload is not working in Firefox , Safari , Opera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645011/window-onbeforeunload-and-window-onunload-is-not-working-in-firefox-safari-o/21455923#21455923)

This solution works great across all browsers, however now I cannot unbind this event on any of my local clicked links! I tried everything

```
window.removeEventlistener('beforeunload',null,false);
window.removeEventlistener('onbeforeunload',null,false);
window.removeBeforeUnload();
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

I hope you can point me in the right direction and explain why I cannot unbind this event, that I used from stackoverflow answer.Thanks!

Comment: As much as I hate you for using an unload event modal, this is a good question because I encountered the same issue trying to capture the close event on a browser without capturing the refresh, back, etc.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Thanks! I hope I can solve this because I'm at the bang head against desk stage! I don't know why the event listeners are not being unregistered!?

Comment: I would suggest sticking with either jQuery-style `bind/unbind` (actually those should be `on/off` in more recent versions of jQuery), or plain DOM-style `addEventListener/removeEventListener` semantics. Combining the two leads to madness :).

Comment: You may want to look at this: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api#the-unload-event

Answer (score 1):

One thought is use a global variable flag and don't do anything in the unload event handler when flag isn't truthy. Set this flag to null or false in link click handlers

Then you don't really need to remove the listener

```
var doUnload = true;

$('a').click(function(){
   doUnload = false;
});

function unloadhandler(){
    if(doUnload){
       // show modal , return message etc
    }else{
       // do nothing , don't return anything
    }       
}
```

Comment: This solution works great on IE where internal website links are sanitized and popup only shows on exit/close, however in FF, the internal links are sanitized, but on exit/close the "Do you want to leave this site" alert stopped showing all together...the popup just shows for millisecs before redirect or close...

Comment: What does internal links are sanitized mean?

Comment: it means, they don't trigger the popup when clicking internal website links

Comment: i have done this before , i remember that returning false or null was a problem in IE but i think worked in other browsers...i just don't remember exactly how i set it up

Comment: there are probably libraries for this since it's really common these days to pop stuff up when you blur the window or try to leave

Answer (score 1):

Probably jQuery is adding a 2nd `beforeunload` event listener, which you can't remove via the DOM API the same way as the one added to the `Window` by default.

What should work for you is:

```
var allLinks = $('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
    $(allLinks[i]).on('click', () => {
      $(window).off('beforeunload');
      // now add any custom code you want for handling this event
      $("#sModal").modal('show');
    )};
  }
```