# Safari: onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

Precondition: You should be on **Safari 10**.

Hi, I'm have trouble getting the Leave | Stay confirmation box to show up on my page across different browsers.

Please go to https://www.biznessapps.com/cms, and login with following credentials:

```
username: pzheng64@gmail.com
password: skl@0!_~!(
```

After you've logged in, go to the /welcome page. Please click Settings in the left sidebar and go to the Membership tab.

If you can see "Enable Membership Features", then click it and change anything there and navigate to another page. You will see the confirmation box show up the first time you try to leave the page.
[image: onbeforeunload confirmbox]

Click "Leave" to go to your target page, and then come back to this Settings page and try the same action; you won't see the confirmation box again (when using Safari).

I used this code snippet at: https://www.biznessapps.com/cms/v2/public/scripts/pages/settings.js?v=68.160720

```
/* settingsPages.isChanged() is my custom function */
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
    if (settingsPage.isChanged()) {
        event.returnValue = "some string";
        return "some string";
    }
});
```

It works fine on Google Chrome and Firefox, but not on Safari.

Thanks!

Comment: @zerk It should be "After you've logged in, you will be redirected to the /welcome page."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.onbeforeunload and window.onunload is not working in Firefox , Safari , Opera?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645011/window-onbeforeunload-and-window-onunload-is-not-working-in-firefox-safari-o)

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: @dario No, I could't find. This question is never duplicate of the article GAntoine mentioned.

Comment: I opened another question, just in case...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014003/onbeforeunload-on-safari-not-displaying-the-confirm-message?noredirect=1#comment69236495_41014003

Comment: @dario why did you open another ticket? any special reason?

Comment: I've done some different tests and it's quite a different code.

Comment: It also doesn't work on *Safari 9*.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely due to Safari's Back-Forward cache. A decent article on this can be found here:
https://team.goodeggs.com/you-forgot-about-bfcache-f7a9bdeceb6c#.qgri9etsb

The fix is to basically just reload the page if it is loaded from the cache, like so:

```
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
    if (event.persisted) {
        window.location.reload() 
    }
};
```

`event.persisted` is the magic part. It is `true` if the page was loaded using the browsers "back" or "forward".