# onbeforeunload on safari not displaying the confirm message

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I have this portion of code that works on all browsers except on `Safari 10.*` (iOS and OSX)

The problem is that Safari fires the `beforeunload event` but it doesn't display on the confirmation message

```
function goodbye(e) {
    console.log("goodbye");
    en = false;

    e = e || window.event;

    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = msg;

    if (!en) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(e.stopPropagation)
        e.stopPropagation();
        return e.returnValue;
    }
}

jQuery(window).bind("beforeunload", goodbye);
```

The good bye message is displayed from the console, so the event is fired on Safari, but the confirmation message (also tried to `return confirm(msg);` instead of `return e.returnValue;` ) is not displayed. Spent a lot of hours on that and have seen a lot of questions here on SO but noone seems to have a working solution.

**EDIT**

it's happening something strange here. If I load the page and refresh once, the message is appearing, then if I leave the page clicking on the leave button and re-refresh it on the same window tab, the message is not appearing.

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: no errors in console. Also tryed to console.log(e.returnValue); before the return e.returnValue; and it prints

Comment: also tried with a blank page with only that javascript code.

Comment: `console.log("goodbye);` should be `console.log("goodbye");`

Comment: yes, it was an error in copying from my code... I wrote with the "

Comment: it's happening something strange here. If I load the page and refresh once, the message is appearing, then if I leave the page clicking on the leave button and re-refresh it, the message is not appearing.