# Bug confirmation and filing advice for beforeunload event in Safari (webkit?) w/ console closed

Tags: javascript, html

Given a webpage that sets the `beforeunload` event handler in the Safari browser *and* the development console is closed, the `beforeunload` handler cannot always prevent navigation away from the webpage. When the development console is open, the handler almost always can prevent navigation away from the page.

This may be reproduced in two ways.

#### Reproducible Method 1

Using a Safari Browser (`Version 12.0.3 (13606.4.5.3.1)`) visit the following `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onbeforeunload = (evt) => { evt.preventDefault(); evt.returnValue = false; return true; };
    </script>
    <p>hello, world!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

then, open the development console, select the navigation bar, type `www.ibm.com` and hit return. An alert will appear prompting the user to "Stay" or "Leave".

Close the console, retry the navigation, a prompt may or may not appear. If it does appear and is not clicked within 2-5 seconds ("Stay"), the new page will be visited although the prompt will remain. Clicking on the prompt has no apparent affect after that.

#### Reproducible Method 2

Using a Safari browser begin to answer a stackoverflow question. Open the development console, then using the navigation bar attempt to visit another site. An alert should appear guarding against loss of form data. Then, close the development console and re-attempt the navigation. This time, the navigation should go through and no alert will be displayed or, if too long before selecting "Stay", navigation will continue.

#### Discussion

1. Can anyone else reproduce this?
2. Advice on whether I should file a bug against Safari or Webkit is welcome.
3. I've tested Method 1 on Firefox and did not see the same behavior - `beforeunload` acted mostly as expected.
4. Have I failed to conjure the `onbeforeunload` function in just the correct way?
5. I first saw this using Angular (with rxjs), however, as I've been able to reproduce it with straight HTML and in another website, this has nothing to do with Angular.

#### EDIT (2019-06-18)

Marked as possible duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938707/safari-onbeforeunload). It is not because that question explores a bug due to back button and bf history caching in Safari. This problem occurs without pressing the Back Button. If it is related somehow to the browser cache mentioned in the associated bug, someone will have to explain that to me, as I cannot see any obvious connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safari: onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938707/safari-onbeforeunload)

Comment: @Herohtar thanks for the quick response. IMO, in a skim of the possible dup and its associated links, I don't think it's a dup, although there are some intriguing items referenced in there that I'd like to understand better.