# Page loading overlay not shown on Safari when navigating to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overlay, show-hide

I have a web application that displays an overlay only when the page is loading (some server work).
It works fine in Firefox and Chrome. For example when I login: i fill in the login form, then I click the login button, the overlay appears - while the server checks, then after a moment, another page is served or an error message is displayed.

The overlay won't display using Safari.

**HTML code**

```
<div class="overlay"  style="display: none;" id="loadingDiv">
```

**javascript - jquery**

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { $("#loadingDiv").show(); };
```

In safari: when I manually comment out the HTML initial hidden state - it shows. (That indicates that my CSS is alright.)  But that's not how it should function.

I tried using `opacity: 0` instead and the whole page is frozen.

How I get the overlay to appear only on page loads - like in Chrome?

Comment: possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645011/window-onbeforeunload-and-window-onunload-is-not-working-in-firefox-safari-o - doesn't look like safari supports it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: instead of `onbeforeunload`, why not do the server check using `jQuery.ajax`, by showing the overlay onsubmit, then redirect to another page or error page on success callback?

Comment: @YongQuan I'll try.  Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chatting with Siavas. I decided to handle action for form submissions and some clicks to trigger the overlay.

Here is my resulting javascript:

```
function init() {
    var forms = document.forms;
    for (var i = forms.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        forms[i].onsubmit = function() {
            $("#loadingDiv").show();
        };
    }
    var subnav = document.querySelectorAll("ul.subnav li a");
    subnav.forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener("click", function () {
            $("#loadingDiv").show();
        });
    });
}
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        init();
    }
});
```

At the bottom, a listener is added, upon being ready the init function is executed.  The overlay is shown for each form submission.  Then a listener is added for clicks (on ul.subnav > li > a) that also shows the overlay. This works in all browsers. Like Tom was showing.

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth using a display attribute...

here I use JS to hide the div on load then when you click the button the div is made visible by removing the hide attribute

```js
     $(document).ready(function () {
        //on page load
        //Adding the attribute and hides the div
        $("#loadingDiv").attr('hidden', 'hidden');
        //on a button click (this could be any event)
        $("#ContanerName").on("click", "#btn", function () {
          //removes the attribute and makes it visable
          $("#loadingDiv").removeAttr('hidden');
        });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ContanerName">
      <div class="overlay" id="loadingDiv">
        <p>hello world</p>
      </div>
      <input type="button" id="btn" value="button"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Although it's a good idea, the overlay is supposed to be displayed on each and every page load - not just for the login.  Because others wrote most of the code, I cannot modify every (100s) click-action (mostly <a... - not all).

Comment: Add the JS code to the master page or if your using MVC it will be the _layout page you need.

This will then be user across the entire site.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `onbeforeunload` is not supported by Safari, but [the recommended approach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Example) in MDN is:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) { 
    $("#loadingDiv").show();
});
```

This script has to be placed after loading jQuery, and preferably at the end of the `<body>` tag. Even better, wrap it with `.ready()` so that it is executed once the entire DOM has been loaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display: none;" id="loadingDiv"><div class="loader">Loading...</div></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) { 
        $("#loadingDiv").show();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This was tested in Safari 12, Chrome 71 and Firefox 64.

Comment: My HTML looks like:
...<script>
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) { 
   $("#loadingDiv").show();
  });
 </script> 
</head>
<body>
 <div style="display: none;" id="loadingDiv"><div class="loader">Loading...</div></div>...

What is missing?

Comment: OK the only difference now is jQuery is loaded in the <head> section and the application uses an old version (1.2).  JQuery is only for the $().show right? and $().ready. So will it work with plain js?

Comment: @YumaTechnicalInc. didn't notify you yet as there is a different behaviour when trying to manipulate the DOM (as in, trying to show some content). Looking to find whether this is possible or not allowed in Safari.

Comment: In the meantime try with the following snippet and look at the Developer Console to see that the event is being handled: `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) { 
    console.log('Leaving page...');
});`

Comment: it responded "undefined". And nothing happened on another page load... FOR YOUR INFORMATION $("#loadingDiv").show(); responded: {0: <div id="loadingDiv">, length: 1, context: #document, selector: "#loadingDiv", init: function, jquery: "1.2.6", …} = $1 and the overlay showed.

Comment: Which Safari version are you using? I also have to mention that this may not work on snippet websites such as jsfiddle. Have you tried it on your environment?

Comment: Safari 12.0.2 MacOS Mojave

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187505/discussion-between-yuma-technical-inc-and-siavas).

Comment: @YumaTechnicalInc. how did this go finally? It seems the chat page is not found for some reason, shall I make the suggestions mentioned in the chat here in the post as well?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It seems like when I allocated the bounty, the chat closed???? Anyway I decided that my only option was to add code to handle form submissions and some clicks.. It works OK, but further clicks may need handling. I will try to post my code below...